# How to recover json firefox files using photorec testdisk?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, testdisk, photorec, json

On the wiki it *says* that `json` files are supported but `json` file format is not listed when using `photorec` file options.

On the cgsecurity forums, some people have suggested that this is considered a `txt` file although, not one user has confirmed that this works and other users have said that using `txt` does not work.

Does anyone know how to use testdisk `photorec` to recover firefox profile files such as saved logins which use `json` format?

---

If not testdisk or photorec, I am open to using a different application. I am only interested in recovering my firefox files from a crashed gpt drive that will not mount.

Okay so I am NOT talking about recovering an NTFS partition and in fact the information , not a deleted partition, is formatted EXT4 of course because it is Ubuntu.

Comment: "GPT drive" is not very descriptive. Please specify the original file system. Also, why are you thinking about JSON? Firefox stores several data in SQLite databases.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I am sorry, NTFS was the original set up on my Dell Inspiron laptop which shipped with Windows 10. Later, I created a new gpt partition which I formatted EXT4 and also 6GB of swap before installing Ubuntu. I dropped the laptop and the next day it would not boot. I think that I accidentally hit the recovery option on accident once and so I think this has erased the partition table. Gpart told me that it would use the "backup" which I think may be incorrect but I am not sure.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Did you not even read my comment after NTFS? I couldn't care less about the NTFS partition, I want my json files from my ext4 Ubuntu partition. We should be able to downvote bad dispositions.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that I only need the json files because the disk is basically toast anyhow. Recovering the partition now may actually cause more damage and render the data unrecoverable!

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Additionally, the entire partition is like 500GB which is way too large for me to make  a clone or use the methods detailed in the linked answer anyhow.

Comment: Making a clone is the only standard procedure that will ensure no more damage is done on the drive. You could consider using EWF instead of RAW, but still. Working on the damaged drive directly is definitely not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Open a file similar to the one you want to recover with a hex editor like HxD for windows or `xxd` for linux. Note the first characters of the file. Create a custom signature in PhotoRec with this content: `json 0 <first characters of a similar json file>`. Usually, firefox login.json files start with `{"nextId":` so use that if all else fails.